# Question about the decay of $f\in W^{1,2}(\mathbb{R}^2)$

Tags: sobolev-spaces, distribution-theory

I have an exercise which asks to prove or provide a counterexample to the following claim:

Given $f\in W^{1,2}(\mathbb{R}^2)$, there exists a radius $R>0$ such that $\vert f(x)\vert \leq 1$ for every $x\in \mathbb{R}^2\setminus B_R(0)$, where $B_R(0)$ denotes the ball of radius $R$ and centered at the origin.

We have seen that $W^{1,2}(\mathbb{R}^2)=W^{1,2}_0(\mathbb{R}^2)$, where the latter is the closure (w.r.t the $W^{1,2}(\mathbb{R}^2)$ norm) of smooth and compactly supported functions on $\mathbb{R}^2$, so intuition would suggest that functions in $W^{1,2}(\mathbb{R}^2)$ "decay at infinity", but I don't know how to formally prove that $L^p$-convergence of a sequence of compactly supported smooth function implies that the limit function is zero at infinity.

Or if the claim is false, I can't find a counterexample.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Do you know that there exist unbounded functions in $W^{1,2}$ in Dimension 2? If yes, take such a function and consider something like $\sum_n 2^{-n} T_n f$, where f is the unbounded function in the sobolev space and $T_n f$ is a shifted/translated version of f.

Comment: To give a concrete example of the above : the function $\log(\log(\frac 2{|x|}))$ is in $W^{1,2}(B(0,\frac 12))$, which can be checked by verifying integrability (the weak derivative is classical outside zero), but isn't in $L^{\infty}(B(0,\frac 12))$. Then one can use the idea above.